# MVVM WPF Programmatically add Child Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to know how to programmatically add child elements to my view.

```
<controls:Book x:Name="myBook" Width="600" Height="400" Margin="25">
        <controls:Book.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Book.ItemTemplate>

        <!--I would like to add Child Elements here like images or usercontrols-->

    </controls:Book>
```

Comment: Your Book control seems to be derived from ItemsControl. Hence you should bind its `ItemsSource` property to an ObservableCollection of data items. See the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN for an example.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. How do I mark something as the accepted answer? Sorry I'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Book control seems to be derived from `ItemsControl`. Hence you should bind its `ItemsSource` property to an ObservableCollection of data items.

```
<controls:Book ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}" ...>
    ...
</controls:Book>
```

See the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN for more details.